# How to prove that $\sum_{p \leq x} {\log p \over p} = \log x + O(1)$?

Tags: asymptotics, analytic-number-theory

## Problem

Prove that
$$
\sum_{p \leq x} {\log p \over p} = \log x + O(1)
$$
as $x \to \infty$.

Notes: $p$ ranges over primes, $\log$ is natural

## Progress

Using Riemann-Stieltjes integration and integration by parts, I think you can write the sum as
$$
\int_2^x {\log t \over t} d\pi(t) = O(1) - \int_2^x {1 - \log t \over t^2} \pi(t) dt.
$$
From here, I tried using the prime number theorem, specifically
$$
\pi(x) = \operatorname{li}(x) + O(xe^{-c\sqrt{\log x}}),
$$
together with
$$
\operatorname{li}(x) = {x \over \log x} + {x \over \log^2 x} + O\Big({x \over \log^3 x}\Big).
$$
All the terms cancel out perfectly except for the integrals of the error terms from the prime number theorem, which diverge. If they converged, they could go into the $O(1)$ term, which would finish the proof.

*Please note that this is tagged as homework.*

---

Those integrals actually do converge. In fact,
$$
O(xe^{-c\sqrt{\log x}}) = O\Big({x \over \log^3 x}\Big),
$$
so there is no need to even consider them separately. I will submit this as an answer to the question this is a duplicate of now.